# css height and overflow

Tags: html, css

i have a problem about height properties.
i am making a website and a want to make this : there is a div element which collapse others and this has a child div and when i resize the window height then the parent div get the window height . it is ok but child div not fixing so some child elements are is this not showing . those are stay down of child div ... plase help me ...

i want to see full patch of yellow area but when i resize the browser height some p tags stay down ... how can i fix it  ?  whatever browser height yellow patch must shown ... please help me ...

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <style>
 *, *:before, *:after{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 html,body{
  height:100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
 }
 .d{
 }
 .d1{
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
 }
 .d2{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  background:yellow;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height:90%;
 }
 .d3{
  height:90px;
  background:blue;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="d d1">
  <div class="d3">
   <p>dadsdsaasd</p>
   <p>dadsdsaasd</p>
   <p>dadsdsaasd</p>
   <p>dadsdsaasd</p>
   <p>dadsdsaasd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="d2">
   <p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>assaddsa</p><p>sonososososo</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `position:inherit` for the child divs. Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

You can use css `calc`.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ye1gtguc/1/)

```
.d2
{
    height: calc( 100% - 90px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Height in pixels and percentage together doesn't work great usually. Overflow:hidden hides the 90% div since its beyond the viewport size. Remove overflow:hidden for the parent div, body & html tag to view hidden contents. If there is any specific reason for overflow:hidden to top hierarchy. You can still achieve the same by mentioning percentage values for both child div

According to your code 
.d2{height:87%}
.d3{height:13%}